# Is there a way to save canvas drawing in flutter to firebase other than converting it to image

Tags: firebase, flutter

i am creating a flutter app where the user has a canvas which he can draw on and then he can save the canvas to Firestore and can recall and edit whenever he wants.I have seen tutorials in creating a canvas and drawing on it but i dont know how to save it to firebase, i have seen some say to convert it as an image and save it to firebase storage but after saving it as an image can the user recall and edit it , and is it possible to save all the points the user has drawn on canvas in the form of a list
Below is a code i am working on,
In this i am trying to save all the points in a list and update it to firebase

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  List<Offset> _points = <Offset>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Container(
        child: new GestureDetector(
          onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
            setState(() {
              RenderBox object = context.findRenderObject();
              Offset _localPosition =
              object.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
              _points = new List.from(_points)..add(_localPosition);
            });
          },
          onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) => _points.add(null),
          child: new CustomPaint(
            painter: new Signature(points: _points),
            size: Size.infinite,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.save),
        onPressed: () => Firestore.instance.collection('points').document('XcX3MbUWt3hiBJyiPMIO'
        ).updateData({'points':FieldValue.arrayUnion(_points)})
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Signature extends CustomPainter {
  List<Offset> points;

  Signature({this.points});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 10.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      if (points[i] != null && points[i + 1] != null) {
        canvas.drawLine(points[i], points[i + 1], paint);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(Signature oldDelegate) => oldDelegate.points != points;
}
```

It gives an error

```
Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'Offset'
```

Is this method of saving possible of so how to do

I am able to print the offsets of the canvas

Comment: If the error comes from the `addData(taskData)` method, we'll need to know what `taskData` is

Comment: Hi sorry , addData future had nothing to do with this.It was there by mistake.I have edited it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include exactly where the error comes from.